# 3 conditions in one if statement

Tags: java, if-statement

This program is supposed to check if the entered year is a leap year or not. But I'm already running into errors while compiling.
The formula to check if it's a leap year or not is the following:

> If you can divide the year by 4 it's a leap year...
>
> unless you can at the same time also divide it by 100, then it's not a
>   leap year...
>
> unless you can at the same time divide it by 400 then it's a leap
>   year.

```
public class Schaltjahr {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        double d;
        String eingabe;
        eingabe = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Gib das Jahr ein "); //Type in the year
        d = Double.parseDouble(eingabe);
        if ((d % 4 == 0) & (d % 100 == 0) && (d % 400 = 0) ) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Es ist ein Schaltjahr"); //It is a leap year
        } else {
            if ((d % 4 == 0) & (d % 100 == 0) )) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Es ist kein Schaltjahr"); //It is not a leap year
            }
        } else {
            if (d % 4 == 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Es ist ein Schaltjahr"); // It is a leap year
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While compiling i get this error:

```
Schaltjahr.java:16: error: illegal start of expression
             if ((d % 4 == 0) & (d % 100 == 0) )) {
                                                ^
Schaltjahr.java:19: error: 'else' without 'if'
         } else {
           ^
2 errors
```

Comment: Since I hope you know what `else` mean .. how should the program decide which `else` block to use?

Comment: Instead of writing `else { if (...) {...} }`, write `else if (...) {...}`.

Comment: Also, in a couple of places you're using `&` when you mean `&&`.

Comment: Sometimes the publishers will have the code on their website! See if there's a reference somewhere in the book or on their site.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just put a *single condition*:

```
 if ((d % 4 == 0) && (d % 100 != 0) || (d % 400 == 0)) {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Es ist ein Schaltjahr"); //It is a leap year
 else     
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Es ist kein Schaltjahr"); //It is not a leap year
```

Since a year is a *leap one* if

```
it divides on 4 AND NOT on 100 OR divides on 400
```

Examples:

```
2016 - leap (divides on 4 and not on 100) 
2000 - leap (divides on 400)
1900 - not leap (divides on 4, but on 100 as well)  
2015 - not leap (doesn't divide on 4, doesn't divide on 400)
```

You may even put it as

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ((d % 4 == 0) && (d % 100 != 0) || (d % 400 == 0)) 
  ? "Es ist ein Schaltjahr"
  : "Es ist kein Schaltjahr");
```

but I guess it's *less readable*.

Answer (score 3):

You have two consecutive `else` statements, which will not compile.

Transform:

```
} else {
         if ((d % 4 == 0) & (d % 100 == 0) )) {
```

... into...

```
} else if ((d % 4 == 0) & (d % 100 == 0) )) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Single if statement to check leap year is :-

```
if((year % 400 == 0) || ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)))
```